# css help - multiple rules

Tags: css

The hover rules are not being applied. When I view in firebug it doesn't seam to load the rule at all.

What is the correct way to implement the hover below?\

The html markup is:

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a target="_blank" title="Click here" href="http://........" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">
<span class="apptitle">Some Text here</span>
<br>
<span class="descrip">Some Description</span>
</a>
<a target="_blank" href="http://......" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><img src="someimg.gif">Please click here for support</a>     
<hr align="center" width="80%"></li>
```

Thanks

```
* html .ui-autocomplete {
width: 400px;
height: 200px;
}
.apptitle, .apptitle a, .apptitle a:active, .apptitle a:visited {
color: #0080FF;
font-weight: bold;

}
 .apptitle a:hover{
text-decoration: underline; 
}
.title {
text-align: left;
}
.descrip, .descrip a, .descrip a:active, .descrip a:visited {
padding-left: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
text-align: left;
color: #000000
}
.descrip a:hover{
 color: #FF6600
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of the html markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting your codes for sake of simplicity first.

HTML

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
    <a href="xxx" class="ui-corner-all">
        <span class="apptitle">Some Text here</span>
        <br>
        <span class="descrip">Some Description</span>
    </a>
    <a href="yyy" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">
        <img src="someimg.gif">
        Please click here for support
    </a>
    <hr align="center" width="80%">
</li>
```

CSS

```
* html .ui-autocomplete {width: 400px; height: 200px;}

.apptitle, .apptitle a, .apptitle a:active, .apptitle a:visited {
color: #0080FF;font-weight: bold;
}
 .apptitle a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}

.title {text-align: left;}

.descrip, .descrip a, .descrip a:active, .descrip a:visited {
padding: 10px 0px 0px 10px; text-align: left; color: #000000
}

.descrip a:hover {color: #FF6600;}
```

OK, now we can analyze it.

For your hovers, you are using:

```
.apptitle a:hover {}
.descrip a:hover {}
```

However, in the HTML structure we see the apptitle is a span inside a link, and without any  inside it, thus the rule will not work.

You can use

```
.apptitle:hover
```

directly, fetching the hover on span tag. This works well with all major browsers, expect IE6, and dunno about IE7. IE8+ works fine.

Or alternatively you can use:

```
a:hover .apptitle {}
```

This ensure the rules will apply only to span at link hover.

In a last word: the problem was in your selectors. Hope you enjoy the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There are the correct order for :link pseudo-class:

a:link {color:#FF0000}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF}  /* selected link */

If you show us the markup, maybe we can help u more quickly.

=D

Comment: A useful mnemonic for remembering the correct cascade order for pseudo link classes is "LoVe-HAte", L(ink) V(isited) H(over) A(ctive)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the markup I suspect you have the class of the anchor in the wrong position try

```
a.descrip:hover {
  color: #FF6600}
```

This is for markup like this

```
<a href="#" class="descrip">
```

Your CSS is for something like

```
<div class="descrip"><a href="#">
```

if this is what the markup is like try

```
div.descrip a:hover { ...
```

Comment: I have had the construct #idname a:hover{} work, and so the construct .classname a:hover{} should also work.